# Node Eclipse - Run and Debug - what is --tea-pot-mode

Tags: eclipse, node.js, command-line-interface, nodeclipse

When I am running a node.js project in run or debug mode, node eclipse is appending --tea-pot-mode to the CLI arguments. I have searched the the IDE, documentation and the web but could not find anything that talks to what tea-pot-mode is and how to disable this.

Anybody know what --tea-pot-mode is and how to disable it in Node Eclipse debug and run CLI args?

Answer (score 1):

This is joke inspired by [HTTP code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_code) 418

> 418 I'm a teapot (RFC 2324)
>       This code was defined in 1998 as one of the traditional IETF April Fools' jokes, in RFC 2324, Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol, and is not expected to be implemented by actual HTTP servers.

You should have checked Window -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse.

It will not be default from Nodeclipse 0.12